# 5 wire universal motor wiring for DC

Tags: wiring

I have a dual voltage 115/230v universal motor, which I need assistance connecting to DC power.

The model is a Model D671B FASCO 1/15 hp 1550 RPM 115/208-230V with Industry number 1231.GE.
The motor works fine in AC, but, I have not been able to get it to spin on DC. The wiring diagram shows only AC connections.
I have been able to test leads where can get 16ohms, these are blue to black, blue to orange, and red to yellow. With the ohm meter connected, each coil pair changes resistance showing brushes attached. another connection between black and orange gave 1 ohm.

In addition, I have tried attaching the red coil in series.

Any advice? The motor cannot be disassembled, so I cannot identify the wire connections.

Comment: What made you presume  an HVAC motor works on DC?

Comment: I have the box the motor came in. It is a "Universal Motor" All universal motors can work on AC or DC... All that has to be done is ensure the coils are wired in series with the brushes

Comment: It's AC according to https://www.zoro.com/fasco-hvac-motor-oao-115-hp-1550-rpm-face-d671b/i/G7473322/.

Comment: This is a shaded Pole type, so assumption is incorrect

Comment: This is an easy to follow tutorial of some common motors which work with 1 phase AC https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zsMkuB9eMDg . They cannot use DC. Motors which can use both DC and AC have a commutator with brushes or complex electronics which generate multiphase AC.

Comment: In this case, the manufacturer means that it is a *universal replacement fan motor* - it can be used to replace a wide variety of fan motors from various manufacturers. It is not a series-wound brushed motor, AKA a *universal motor*.

Answer (score 0):

The type of motor, you have is shaded 4 poles motor. It does not have brushes and has squirrel cage rotor. That types of motors work only AC. Connection can be made only according to label on body.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I had multiple part numbers, and the box with conflicting information. Multiple sources also noted universal. Well, at least I can use it as a generator.

Comment: Asynchronous motor with squarrel cage rotor can not work as generator. Package may be universal but motor is not.

Comment: The search gives https://www.regalbeloit.com/products/motors/low-voltage-nema-motors/hvac-r-motors/refrigeration-motors/1-15-hp-refrigeration-motor-1550-rpm-115-208-230-volts-3-3-diameter-semi-enclosed-fan-cooled-d671b

Comment: Im probably gonna dismantle the motors, but they can work as a generator, if run above asynchronous speed. Residual magnetism has to build up... although you can magnetize a coil manually, then proceed to spin.

Comment: You can make some voltage output but not big current.